# Creating Sorted Map within Lua UDF

Tags: lua, aerospike

In the Aerospike Java client, a sorted map can be created via the `MapOrder` property, such as `MapOrder.KEY_ORDERED` or `MapOrder.KEY_VALUE_ORDERED`.

Within a Lua UDF, the [docs](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/map.html) indicate several ways to create a CDT map, but none allow specifying a map order:

```
local m1 = map()                       -- create map
local m2 = map.create(100)             -- create with initial size
local m3 = map { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 } -- create with initial state
```

Is it possible to do so purely within a Lua UDF? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to, within Lua, create a Map with non-default sort order (e.g. KEY_ORDER). However:

1. If a record is created by the Java client with a certain Map Policy, the policy will be *maintained* even if the record is edited via Lua; and
2. If a Map is created in Lua, the Java Client can set the map policy separately afterwards.